# Alternative ways to input text on field

Tags: appium, robotframework

I need to test this login form on iOS Emulator, but when I try to insert text on element `'//input[@name="email"]'` the text is putted however when I select the element `'//input[@name="password"]'` the text from the first element disappear, the same happens when I press the `'//div[@id="react-component-login-header']//button/div/span[1]"` element.

I think the problem is related how the Text is inputted in form, since that using Selenium2Library (for Desktop) don't have this problem.

Any other way how I can insert text on the field? I don't have any problem in using other Libraries or creating Keywords on Python to auxiliary the tests (already did on other tests).

I already tried with:

- Input Text
- Input Value
- Input Password (I know, but i needed to try something else)

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Dialogs
Library           AppiumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${defaultTimeout}    15s

*** Test Cases ***
TC001
    [Setup]    Configuration
    Start Test
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    //*[@id='age-gate-yes']    ${defaultTimeout}
    Click Element    //a[@id='age-gate-yes']
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    //a[@href="/profile"]    ${defaultTimeout}
    Click Element    //a[@href="/profile"]
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    //input[@name="email"]    ${defaultTimeout}
    Click Element    //input[@name="email"]
    Input Text    //input[@name="email"]    johndoe@john.doe
    Click Element    //input[@name="password"]
    Input Text    //input[@name="password"]    JohnDoe123
    Click Element    //div[@id='react-component-login-header']//button/div/span[1]
    Wait Until Page Does Not Contain Element    //div[@id='react-component-login-header']//button/div/span[1]    ${defaultTimeout}
    [Teardown]    End Test
```

I can see the text being written on field, but when the context of that element is lost, the text is too.

Comment: i don't get how you to tried to input text. you can try **sendKey()** method. `driver.findElementById("element id").sendKey("your text")`

Comment: I tried using the keyword Input Text from AppiumLibrary: 

AppiumLibrary.Input Text    //input[@name="email"]    johndoe@john.doe

Comment: Did you tried **sendKey()** method?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but in which Library that method is in? I already tried the Library SendKeys but wihout success, it type on my desktop and not on Virtual Machine or Emulator.

Comment: it is defined in **org.openqa.selenium.remote**

Comment: Did you added **java-client** and **selenium-java** library in your project?

Comment: I really can't see how I can put this working...


I did not, should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android I resolve the problem using the keyword "AppiumLibrary.Press Keycode"

Example, sending a "AppiumLibrary.Press Keycode    67" I managed to send a backspace

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html